# Save geolocation as latitude/longitude or address/area name?

Tags: mysql, database-design, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Suppose a service like Foursquare, I want to save the location of a check-in. Should I save this as latitude-longitude or the address/area name such as 123 Portmill St, NY 12345 or SoHo, NY.
In the first case, I can have users type an address and my service looks up and stores lat-long information. By doing this my service can search check-ins within a polygon-boundary.

While on the second case, I can store location as a bucket and avoid redundant information such as (lat,long) = (100000.1,100000.1), (100000.2,100000.2) which are very close together and can even be considered the same location.

Comment: can they check in from the middle of a field? probably not. i'd say check in from nearest location, not the lat/lon

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've completely understood the nuances of what you're trying to do, but computers usually work better with numbers like latitude and longitude rather than human-readable text information.  For example, with the text address, how would you ensure consistency, e.g. dealing with extra spaces, ZIP+4 codes rather than just shorter zip codes etc etc.

I guess it's just my instinct that latitude and longitude might be better than text.  Where I live in the UK, there are a lot of examples where towns and cities have two roads of the same name, so I do think that there are likely to be more pitfalls with storing text instead of latitude/longitude.

Comment: For those, I can use Google reverse geocoder which outputs the name or address of a place or region. Since a region consists of a bunch of points, instead of storing all of them, have the database store a common region and use google's reverse geocoder to look up the point's region name.

Comment: You mean text isn't digital?  News to me!  ;)

Comment: @WalterMitty thanks, I've made what I hope you think is an appropriate edit to my my answer.

Comment: good fix.  I'd add to your comment that it's easy to compute air distance between two places identified by latitude and longitude. Not so with text.

Comment: @Stochastically Then how do you recommend dealing with redundant data points that describe the same location?

Comment: A good answer to that probably depends on some of the details of what you're trying to do that I'm not familiar with.  However, I guess you could either (1) reverse geocode nearby points to see whether they're the same, or (2) Have a minimum distance so that you only keep one point when two points are close to each other.

Comment: Another thought regarding storing text is that different geocoding schemes may return different text, or perhaps a revised version of the same geocoder might also have slightly different text to its previous version.  But no one is going to redefine Latitude and Longitude!

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  I'd store 3 columns in the database, namely (Latitude, Longitude, TextLocation), but it's the pair (Latitude, Longitude) that's regarded as the key of the table.  The TextLocation is just the last known result from the reverse geocoder when the geocoder was asked for the text corresponding to the given (Latitude, Longitude).

When a new position arrives, (New_Latitude, New_Longitude), I'd search the database to find all closest rows in the database.  To calculate distance of (New_Latitude, New_Longitude) to (Latitude, Longitude), I'd use the following code

```
float LatDiff = New_Latitude - Latitude;
float LongDiff = New_Longitude - Longitude;
float CosNewLat = Math.cos(New_Latitude);
float ConversionFac = 6371000 * Math.PI / 180; // 6371000 is earth radius in metres
float Dist_metres = ConversionFac * Math.sqrt(LatDiff*LatDiff + LongDiff*LongDiff*CosNewLat*CosNewLat);
```

Then for each of the closest points to (New_Latitude, New_Longitude), I'd update the TextLocation in the database using reverse geocoding.  If the new position doesn't match the current reverse geocoding for any of the existing locations, I'd add it into the database.

Part of my thinking here is that even storing 3 columns which includes a column of text, the database is still going to be tiny compared to modern storage capacities.